# Sqlite 3 Python Operational Error: sqlite3.OperationalError Create table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('food.db')
print("Opened Database Successfully")

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE ORDER
        (ORDERID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        FOODID INT NOT NULL,
        CUSTOMERID INT NOT NULL,
        DATEOFORDER CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
        PRICEOFORDER REAL NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTID),
            FOREIGN KEY (FOODID) REFERENCES FOOD(FOODID));''')

conn.close()
```

Created this code, and I'm getting an error message as an operational error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error
```

The customer and food tables have been created, and they both work

Comment: Provide the full error you are getting

Comment: OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved word in SQL, you'll need to *quote* it to be able to use it as a table name. Put it in *double quotes*:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE "ORDER"
        (ORDERID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        FOODID INT NOT NULL,
        CUSTOMERID INT NOT NULL,
        DATEOFORDER CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
        PRICEOFORDER REAL NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTID),
            FOREIGN KEY (FOODID) REFERENCES FOOD(FOODID));''')
```

You could use `[ORDER]` and `` `ORDER` `` too, but those use non-standard syntax.

See the [*SQLite keywords* documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).